# dapper Error converting data type datetime to smalldatetime when executing stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I have a table in my database with smalldatetime type. And I have a stored procedure that updates data in that table.

The stored procedure gets a `@LastLogin smalldatetime` parameter with the date to update.

In c# I have a code that calls the stored procedure using dapper:

```
loginDetails.LastLoginDate = (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;
db.Execute("stp_UpdateLogin", loginDetails, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error converting data type datetime to smalldatetime.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader) in d:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 3310
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command) in d:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 1310
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in d:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 1185
   at Memoriez.Repositories.UsersRepository.UpdateUser(User user) in f:\Development\Memoriez\Memoriez.Repositories\UsersRepository.cs:line 58
ClientConnectionId:02cae914-507b-4c21-9799-8ec0940fc3d9
```

How can I make sure that dapper passes what SQL expects?

Answer (score 2):

That's because

```
(DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue = 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM
```

While the minimum value for

```
SMALLDATETIME  = 1900-01-01 00:00:00
```

---

You could create a helper class:

```
public static class SqlSmallDateTime
{
    public static readonly SqlDateTime MinValue = new SqlDateTime(new DateTime(1900, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00));
}
```

Comment: is there a MinValue object for smalldatetime in c# like there's one for datetime?

Comment: @developer82, unfortunately no. You have to define the min as `new DateTime(1900, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);`